# Cannot get the top window or list of all windows

Tags: c#

The following piece of code is in a Window Service, it is supposed to output to a text file, firstly the name of the top window, then a list of all the visible windows. This process occurs when the service first starts.

Unfortunately it doesn't spit out anything, OutputTopWindow doesn't output anything, I would have expected "Computer Management" as the top window as I have to start the service from computer management.

ListAllVisibleWindows does not return anything either. I have several windows visible when OutputWindowInfo is called, running this service locally on Win7 64bit.

Why would this be occurring?

```
public void OutputWindowInfo()
{
    OutputTopWindow();
    ListAllVisibleWindows();
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);


private void OutputTopWindow()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        WriteMessageLog( Buff.ToString() );
    }
}

public delegate bool EnumDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

public static void ListAllVisibleWindows()
{
    List<string> collection = new List<string>();
    EnumDelegate filter = delegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
    {
        StringBuilder strbTitle = new StringBuilder(255);
        int nLength = GetWindowText(hWnd, strbTitle, strbTitle.Capacity + 1);
        string strTitle = strbTitle.ToString();

        bool winvis = IsWindowVisible(hWnd);
        bool emptyTitle = string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTitle);
        WriteMessageLog(winvis + " " + emptyTitle + " " + strTitle);
        if (winvis && emptyTitle == false)
        {
            collection.Add(strTitle);
        }
        return true;
    };

    if (EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, filter, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            WriteMessageLog(item);
        }
    }
}
public static void WriteMessageLog(String message)
{
    StreamWriter sw = null;
    try
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\LogFile.txt", true);
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + message + ": ");
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

In ListAllVisibleWindows() I have output all of what it finds with `WriteMessageLog(winvis + " " + emptyTitle + " " + strTitle);`, this is the result:

```
False False .NET-BroadcastEventWindow.4.0.0.0.bf7771.0: 
False False HID Input Service: 
False False BMonBRW1C3E84B6FE08: 
False False internal window: 
False True : 
False False Wmi Provider Host: 
False True : 
False False pdfsvc: 
False True : 
False True : 
False False PnPWindow: 
False False VCS Event Handler:900: 
False True : 
False False VCS Event Handler:1632:
```

These are the windows I actually have open: 2 Windows Explorer, Recycle Bin, Firefox, Computer Management, Visual Studio, VS Command Prompt, Notepad

Comment: Lol good to know. So would I just create this as a formless app and pop it into the startup folder.

Comment: Maybe it helpfull to you this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819575/how-to-list-active-application-windows-using-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks Osman this is actually what I used. I believe it will work when I switch it to an application. As stuart has mentioned this has all come about because I've designed it in a service.

Comment: @stuartd maybe you could summarize your comments into an answer and I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because by default since Windows Vista, services run in a separate session:

> In Windows® XP, Windows Server® 2003, and earlier versions of the
> Windows operating system, all services run in the same session as the
> first user who logs on to the console. This session is called Session
> 0. Running services and user applications together in Session 0 poses a security risk because services run at elevated privilege and
> therefore are targets for malicious agents who are looking for a way
> to elevate their own privilege level.
>
> In Windows Vista®, Windows
> Server 2008, and later versions of Windows, the operating system
> mitigates this security risk by isolating services in Session 0 and
> making Session 0 noninteractive. Only system processes and services
> run in Session 0. The first user logs on to Session 1, and subsequent
> users log on to subsequent sessions. This means that services never
> run in the same session as users’ applications and are therefore
> protected from attacks that originate in application code [[source]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For legacy compatibility, [it is possible to change settings so services can interact with the desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson8/) but it is a bad idea from [a security point of view](https://serverfault.com/a/576178/1002) - if you can restructure this so it doesn't have to be a service at all, that would be best.