# Hiding other windows/programs from Electron App

Tags: node.js, windows, hide, show-hide, electron

I've been searching NPM for some package that will allow me, for Windows only Linux and OSX support is not required, to hide specific open windows. For instance I would like to be able to hide and unhide a notepad window, however if I have multiple notepad windows open I do not want to hide them all, I want to hide only a single specific one. I'd like it to be hidden from the task bar and not just have the opacity set to invisible.

Does anyone know of an NPM Package with this functionality or if its even possible?

I believe the equidistant of this in C# would be ShowWindow from user32.dll

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't able to locate a out-of-the-box solution for you, but you hint at the answer to your problem in your question. user32.dll is accessible from node.js/electron using the node-ffi.

To install node-ffi you need node-gyp and all of its dependencies on Windows. See https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation

Next you need to do the following:

```
npm install ffi
npm install electron-rebuild
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

That last one is to rebuild the native binaries for Electron.

Put the following chunk of code in your Electron application:

```
var FFI = require('ffi');

function TEXT(text){
  return new Buffer(text, 'ucs2').toString('binary');
}

var user32 = new FFI.Library('user32', {
  'FindWindowW': ['int', ['string', 'string']],
  'ShowWindow': ['int', ['int', 'int']]
});

var handle = user32.FindWindowW(null, TEXT('Untitled - Notepad'));
console.log(handle);
user32.ShowWindow(handle, 0);
```

Launch notepad and make sure the window title is 'Untitled - Notepad'. If you launch your Electron app the window should hide, but the process remains. I've posted a video that demonstrates that this does work: https://youtu.be/4thydneqtyQ

As for the second half of your question...

You'll need some way to identify which Window you want to hide. If you can use the Window title then the above method will work.

If you cannot then you'll need to have some other way to evaluate the Window via the Win32 API and make the determination. You could use EnumWindows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) via FFI to get every window and then use other functions to inspect it and make the determination.

If you provide exactly how you plan to differentiate I'll see if I can find a specific solution for it. Otherwise my suggestion is to research how to do it via user32.dll using C# or C++ and then translate the result to Electron using FFI.

Comment: Oh damn son, you are the real MvP. I can't thank you enough, you wen't above and beyond the call of duty, tis people like you whom spread goodness around the world, I hope to repay some time some how. Thanks you it is very appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! :-) It took me a while to get FFI working correctly with Electron. That being said, if you have any troubles let me know and I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: Hey, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10819641/3055031 for using EnumWindows from User32.dll, tomorrow I'm gonna try and wrap my head around how to get them to work in Node. Just I don't know what variable type i'd map "WNDENUMPROC" to. Once again thanks for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Also, sorry to be a pain but could you briefly explain why electron-rebuild is needed instead of something like electron-prebuilt? Is it just because ffi is a native module?

Comment: Neat find, and not a pain at all! I am not certain if I fully understand the underlying reason electron-rebuild is needed, but it has to do with the fact that Electron uses a different version of V8 than official Node does and native modules compiled for Node may therefore be out of sync with what Electron is using. There is some explaination here: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md.

Comment: Also, with regards to WNDENUMPROC, check out the code on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491279/node-ffi-callback-extraction-of-enumwindows It looks like the person is using the ffi.Callback method to produce WNDENUMPROC which is otherwise a "pointer" type.

Comment: Huh, I tried converting that code from CoffeeScript back to regular JS to try it out, but I just get an error from within ffi, Uncaught ReferenceError: libm is not defined from within ffi\lib\_foreign_function.js:59 I've tried looking online for other users with this error but to no avail, I'll keep trying.

Comment: Just an update if you were curious, I got EnumWindows working http://stackoverflow.com/a/37737797/3055031

Comment: Yep, I'm doing great, I even turned this into an npm module, [node-hide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-hide). Its still a work in progress of course, but It works and I'm gonna build my electron app on top of this. Mind if I credit you somewhere on there?